# Julia - save workspace

Tags: julia

Is there an official way to save all variables in the workspace? If not, is there a way to display all variables? Right now I use `whos()` but that displays all modules and functions aswell

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think what you want is `@save` and `@load` pair of [JLD.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD.jl).

```
julia> n = 10
10

julia> x = randn(n, n)
10×10 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.0197367  -0.176776    0.25441    1.27037    …   0.922747   -1.62709   -1.00135
 -0.926221    0.0511172   0.616038  -0.876974      -1.38141    -0.663528   0.0851561
 -1.16956     1.33495    -0.192604   0.986576       1.20383    -1.11466    0.654329
 -0.0358511  -2.18456    -0.253529   1.12241       -0.558712   -0.29862    1.52749
 -0.228209    0.21741     0.79077    0.104083      -0.109346    0.206167   1.6082
 -0.255945    0.185782    0.650366  -1.43969    …   0.367013   -1.20504   -3.03426
  0.801956   -1.03232    -0.13117    0.0241593     -0.0129462   2.2469     0.208836
 -1.09213    -0.723174    0.609008   0.175357       0.487224    0.97294    0.770932
 -1.12841     0.249794    0.134091   0.0268805     -0.832201   -1.0924    -1.08669
  0.0170944   0.945585   -0.915999   0.96237        2.03081    -0.800125  -0.584156

julia> using JLD

julia> @save "data.jld"

# restart Julia REPL

julia> using JLD

julia> @load "data.jld"
3-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :ans
 :n
 :x

julia> n
10

julia> x
10×10 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.0197367  -0.176776    0.25441    1.27037    …   0.922747   -1.62709   -1.00135
 -0.926221    0.0511172   0.616038  -0.876974      -1.38141    -0.663528   0.0851561
 -1.16956     1.33495    -0.192604   0.986576       1.20383    -1.11466    0.654329
 -0.0358511  -2.18456    -0.253529   1.12241       -0.558712   -0.29862    1.52749
 -0.228209    0.21741     0.79077    0.104083      -0.109346    0.206167   1.6082
 -0.255945    0.185782    0.650366  -1.43969    …   0.367013   -1.20504   -3.03426
  0.801956   -1.03232    -0.13117    0.0241593     -0.0129462   2.2469     0.208836
 -1.09213    -0.723174    0.609008   0.175357       0.487224    0.97294    0.770932
 -1.12841     0.249794    0.134091   0.0268805     -0.832201   -1.0924    -1.08669
  0.0170944   0.945585   -0.915999   0.96237        2.03081    -0.800125  -0.584156
```

Comment: word of warning: the \@save and \@load macros are specifically for the "base" workspace, and are not intended for use within functions. You need to use the function versions for that (which means either specifying variables to save, or dealing with dictionaries instead, unfortunately)

Comment: equally, `whos()` returns the *global* workspace, not the local one of a function. Just things to keep in mind.

Comment: The Atom/Juno IDE also has a workspace window, really convenient for navigating the workspace.